# Could the improper assignment of my singly linked list be leading to an uninitialized value somewhere?

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind

Hello and thanks to all who bothered to read! I am currently working on a program that uses a singly linked list to print out a pattern based on the first letter of the color element and first element in the details int address array shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    char* color;
    int** details;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

Node* light_info(char *filename){
    Node* head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node* second = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node* third = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node* fourth = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node* fifth = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node* sixth = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    head->next = second;
    second->next = third;
    third->next = fourth;
    fourth->next = fifth;
    fifth->next = sixth;
    sixth->next = NULL;

    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    char* token;
    int num1, num2;
    int* ptr1 = &num1;
    int* ptr2 = &num2;
    char line[250];
    Node* current = head;

    if(head==NULL||second==NULL||third==NULL||fourth==NULL||fifth==NULL||sixth==NULL){
        printf("Error. Program has amnesia, not allocating memory...");
    }
    else{
        while((fgets(line,250,fp)!=NULL)&&(current!=NULL)){
            token = strtok(line, ",\n");
            current->color = malloc(20);
            current->color = token;

            current->details = malloc(sizeof(ptr1)*2);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
            num1 = atoi(token);
            current->details[0]=ptr1;

            token = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
            num2 = atoi(token);
            current->details[1]=ptr2;

            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    return head;    
}

/*Takes a Node pointer as a parameter, and iterates through the linked list,
  printing out a number of dashes for each light's brightness score.*/
void off(Node* h){
    printf("\n***Turning lights off:\n");

    while(h!=NULL){
        int i;
        int* ptr = h->details[0];
        int b = *ptr;

        for(i=0;i<b;i++){
            printf("-");
        }
        printf(" ");
        h=h->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*Takes a Node pointer as a parameter, and iterates through the linked list, 
  printing out the first letter of each color the amount of times each light is bright.*/
void on(Node* h){
    printf("\n***Turning lights on:\n");

    while(h!=NULL){
        int i;
        int* ptr = h->details[0];
        int b = *ptr;

        for(i=0;i<b;i++){
            printf("%c",h->color[0]);
        }
        printf(" ");
        h=h->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*Frees data using Node's head and prints exit message.*/
void Exit(Node* h){
    printf("Exiting...\n");

    Node* temp;
    while(h!=NULL){
        free(h->color);
        free(h->details);
        temp = h;
        h = h->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc < 2||argc >= 3){
        printf("Error. Enter one filename and one filename only.");     
    }
    else{
        char* filename = argv[1];
        Node* head = light_info(filename);
        int vibe_check = 1;
        int Switch = 0;
        char resp[10];

        while(vibe_check){
            if(head == NULL){
                printf("Head memory not allocated...");
                vibe_check = 0;
            }
            else{
                scanf("%s", resp);
                if(strcmp(resp,"off")==0){
                    if(Switch==0){
                        printf("\n--Lights are already off.\n");
                    }
                    else{
                        Switch = 0;
                        off(head);
                    }
                }
                else if(strcmp(resp,"on")==0){
                    if(Switch==1){
                        printf("\n--Lights are already on.\n");
                    }
                    else{
                        Switch = 1;
                        on(head);
                    }
                }
                else if(strcmp(resp,"exit")==0){
                    Exit(head);
                }
                else{
                    printf("Invalid command, type in off, on, or exit.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The data for this program comes from a file formatted like so,

```
blue,2,0
green,1,0
red,1,0
red,2,1
yellow,2,1
blue,1,1
```

The expected out put for the program should be `bb g r rr yy b` any time someone types on with dashes replacing letters when someone types off after the lights are on. However, when run the program prints nothing out and after several rounds of debugging and valgrind, I've noticed two things:

1. The Node structs are not assigned line-by-line, leading to Nodes having duplicates of the last line
   of data gotten rather than individual pieces of data based on the line read.
2. According to valgrind, their is an uninitialized value in the on function that I can't find.

Sorry if this is quite lengthy, but any help would be deeply appreciated! I am open to editing my post and any constructive critique if necessary!

Answer (score 0):

The way you process your input in `light_info` has several errors.

First, `current->color` is assigned some allocated memory, then that memory is lost by the assignment on the next line (`current->color = token;`).  This assignment will not copy the string pointed to by `token`, but will change the value of `color` to point to the same place - which is in the local variable `line` and will be dangling once your function returns.  You'll want to use `strcpy` (or the safer version, `strncpy`) to copy the string into your allocated space.

You do something similar with `current->details[0]=ptr1;`.  `ptr1` points at the local `num1` variable, so this pointer will also become dangling when the function returns.  I'm not sure why `details` is an array of pointers.  An array of `int` (where you can store the values directly) would seem a better choice.  (The same applies to `details[1]` and `ptr2`).

Unrelated to this problem, the error checks for one of the mallocs to have failed are in the wrong place.  You've already dereferenced all those pointers before you check them for NULL.  That check should be up right after you've done the last `malloc`, before you start assigning all those `next` pointers.

There is also a lack of error checking elsewhere.

Comment: the reason why details is an array of pointers is because it's a programming assignment. Can't change it if I don't want to lose credit. Do I make a copy of the details address and deference or assign the data directly as an int?

Comment: @Billthetaxationman Well if those pointers are a requirement you'll have to leave them. You'll probably want to allocate them individually (since each "details" will need to point at its own values), and free them later.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, our professor only taught linked lists a couple days ago. I'm having trouble assigning the pointers individually. I'm using the for loop `for(i=0;i<2;i++){
                current->details = malloc(sizeof(c));
                current->details = c;
                token = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
                num = atoi(token);
                *c = &num;
            }` where int c is an int double pointer. Now I get the error `./a.out: relocation error: ./a.out: symbol strcmp, version  not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference`

Comment: this occurs when I type on.